# PHP/MySQL is there SELECT...INSERT and/or SELECT...INSERT...DELETE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL, and I'm trying to do the following and hoping I can do it all with a single PHP query to MySQL call rather than having to call, store in php, call, store in php etc.

Here's my database setup. 1. table of users, including email address. 2. table of 'invitees' by email address and user who invited the invitee 3. table of 'friends'

I want to join the table of users with the table of invitees to determine which invitees have registered as users and who invited them (keeping in mind they might have been invited by more than 1 person). From there I'll insert the newly registered invitee along with the person who invited him into the friends table. Finally I will delete that invitee from the invited table so that he won't keep receiving invitations.

I see how to do this with 3 separate php calls to mysql: 1. a JOIN to find the users who are in the user table and the invitee table (the join will also identify who invited them) 2. an INSERT to put the pair into the friends table 3. a DELETE to remove the user from the invitee list.

But this will be higher traffic/less optimized with multiple calls to the MySQL server and also a lot of data stored by my php script that I really just need for the next MySQL call. I have a feeling this should be possible in just 1 call with no data returned to the php script.

I see there is an INSERT...SELECT MySQL call (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), but I have not been able to find a way to combine steps 1 and 2 above, which would be a SELECT...INSERT option. Does this exist? I tried the following, but it didn't work...something like this would be my ideal.

```
SELECT users.user as user1, invited2.user as user2, invited2.email as email2 FROM users RIGHT JOIN invited2 ON users.email=invited2.invitee; 
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend) VALUES (user1, user2), (user2, user1);  
DELETE FROM invited2 WHERE invited2.email = email2;
```

The part before INSERT INTO works on its own, but like I said, if I just return that to my php script, I'll just have to store all the results and then call the second myself. Is there a way to do this in one call? And if so, is there a way to also tack on a delete statement (DELETE from invited2 WHERE invitee=users.email) afterwards?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a stored procedure with an `INSERT....SELECT` plus a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the advice. I was thinking of this as a back up plan, but I've heard mixed reviews of stored procedures, particularly for portability and keeping traffic off the database server so I'm hoping to avoid this.

Comment: You should use database servers for heavy lifting where data is concerned and keep as much data manipulation code out of PHP as possible. Stored procedures are *extremely*  portable, whoever gave you bad reviews is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm also a bit confused as to how I would store the data between calls of the stored procedure. For example, once I do the join select, do I need to set it equal to a variable? for example, is the syntax something like this? a = SELECT users.user as user1, invited2.user as user2, invited2.email as email2 FROM users RIGHT JOIN invited2 ON users.email=invited2.invitee; And then what would the INSERT statement look like?

Comment: You would pass variables to the stored procedure.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That seems a bit strange since these variables would be neither IN nor OUT since they're purely for the purpose of passing data between calls within the same procedure?

Comment: You can retrieve and use values in a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does provide a INSERT...SELECT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Your SQL can be edited to:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend)
SELECT users.user as user1, invited2.user as user2
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN invited2 ON users.email=invited2.invitee;

DELETE invited2
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN invited2 ON users.email=invited2.invitee;
```

In this case, INNER JOIN seems to make more sense than RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Could you please also address the `DELETE` requirement of the question as well?

Comment: @Mr.Llama thanks for taking a look. My delete statement would delete rows from invitee where the email address matched the email address of a user from the users table.